Parametrized FactoryBean in Spring
I want the following config to work with Spring
public class MyService {
  @Autowired 
  private DynamoDbTable<Class1> myDep1;
  @Autowired
  private DynamoDbTable<Class2> myDep2;
  @Autowired
  private DynamoDbTable<Class2> myDep3;
}

To generate the DynamoDbTable instance, I can have a method that takes a class, but this won't work
@Bean
public <T> DynamoDbTable<T> genTable(Class<T> clazz) {
   ..
}

This won't work, it won't know where clazz is supposed to come from, and it will only create a singleton DynamoDbTable bean. How can I write the genTable method that will do what i expect, i.e. get a parameter that tells it what class it wants to build, and return an instance for each invocation

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4846310/spring-autowiring-with-generic-factory-built-beans
